# line plot with different line colors and trace style depending on column names of data table

Tags: r, plotly, trace, r-plotly, line-plot

I get a data table `dt.data` from a server that can have the following column names:

```
set.seed(123)
dt.data <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 365),
                      'EEX DEB CAL-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'EEX ATB CAL-2021' = rnorm(365, 4, 2), 
                      'PEGAS TTF CAL-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 2), 'PEGAS NCG CAL-2021' = rnorm(365, 4, 3),
                      'PEGAS AUTVTP CAL-2021' = rnorm(365, 1, 2), 'ICE ATW CAL-2021' = rnorm(365, 3, 2),
                      'ICE BRN CAL-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'EEX FEUA MDEC1' = rnorm(365, 2, 2),
                      check.names = FALSE)
```

The data table can also have fewer columns if, e.g. certain products are omitted. However, it can also be longer if, e.g. not only the year 2021 but also 2022 is viewed for each product. The last column here `"EEX FEUA MDEC1"` is independent of the calendar year and is either presented in the table or not.

A total of 4 different calendar years are possible, but not all 4 must always be present in the table, but only in 2021, as in this case.

I want to create a line plot that gives each product a special color, namely:

`"EEX DEB CAL-"` should have the color `"#007D3C"`

`"EEX ATB CAL-"` should have the color `"#81C07A"`

`"PEGAS TTF CAL-"` should have the color `"#F07D00"`

`"PEGAS NCG CAL-"` should have the color `"#FF9966"`

`"PEGAS AUTVTP CAL-"` should have the color `"#F7BEF7"`

`"ICE ATW CAL-"` should have the color `"#828282"`

`"ICE BRN CAL-"` should have the color `"#993333"`

`"EEX FEUA MDEC1"` should have the color `"#3399FF"`

I would also like to have a different trace type for each calendar year, whereby, e.g. `"EEX DEB CAL-2021"` and `"EEX DEB CAL-2023"` only differ in the trace type and should still have the same color (`"#007D3C"`). Since there are a maximum of 4 different calendar years, I have defined `line_type` in the code below as following:
`line_type <- setNames (c ("line", "dot", "dash", "lines + markers"), colNames)`.

I have already tried it with this code below:

```
colNames <- names(dt.data)[-1]
colors <- setNames(c("#007D3C", "#81C07A", "#F07D00", "#FF9966", "#F7BE7F", "#828282", 
                     "993333", "#3399FF"), colNames)
line_type <- setNames(c("line", "dot", "dash","lines+markers"), colNames)

p <- plotly::plot_ly()
for(trace in colNames){
  p <- p %>% plotly::add_trace(data = dt.data, x = ~date, y = as.formula(paste0("~`", trace, "`")), name = trace,
                               type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', connectgaps = TRUE, 
                               hovertemplate = paste("%{xaxis.title.text}:  %{x}<br>",
                                                     "%{yaxis.title.text}:  %{y}<br>"),
                               line = list(color = colors[[trace]], dash = line_type[[trace]]))
}

p %>% 
  layout(title = "Info",
         xaxis = list(title = "Date"),
         yaxis = list (title = "\u20ac/MWh"))
```

Unfortunately this plot doesn't work.

Is it possible to assign a certain color to a product and design this plot like that? Since the table always looks different and never has the same columns or the columns can appear in different order, I need a very, very flexible and general plot that shows me what I want to have.

Comment: `EEX DEB CAL-2023` doesn't exist in the data you provided.

Comment: Not in this data table, but it is possible that the server not only delivers products for 2021 but also those for 2023. The table would then have 7 additional columns.  ```dt.data``` is only an example data table, but it contains all possible products (without taking the year into account).

Comment: Sure, but for testing it's better to have a representative dataset also including the variable linetype (based on the calender year).

Comment: There is no year given for `EEX FEUA MDEC1`

Comment: Yes, ```EEX FEUA MDEC1``` has no year. It is the only product here without calendar years.

Comment: Just as a side note - please use the `r-plotly` tag for questions referring to R's plotly API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, all you need for this was already given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64440028/define-color-scheme-when-plotting-line-plot-with-plotly/64441221#64441221).

However, I changed your example data a little so you can see the `dot` line.

You should:

1. convert you data from wide to long using `melt.data.table`
2. use valid linetypes: 'solid', 'dot', 'dash', 'longdash', 'dashdot', 'longdashdot'

---

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

set.seed(123)
dt.data <-
  data.table(
    date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 365),
    'EEX DEB CAL-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
    'EEX ATB CAL-2021' = rnorm(365, 4, 2),
    'EEX DEB CAL-2023' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
    'EEX ATB CAL-2023' = rnorm(365, 4, 2),
    'PEGAS TTF CAL-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 2),
    'PEGAS NCG CAL-2021' = rnorm(365, 4, 3),
    'PEGAS AUTVTP CAL-2021' = rnorm(365, 1, 2),
    'ICE ATW CAL-2021' = rnorm(365, 3, 2),
    'ICE BRN CAL-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
    'EEX FEUA MDEC1' = rnorm(365, 2, 2),
    check.names = FALSE
  )

DT <- melt.data.table(dt.data, id.vars = "date")
DT[, c("product_name", "calendar_year") := tstrsplit(variable, "-")]
DT[, "calendar_year" := lapply(.SD, function(x){ifelse(is.na(x),"none",x)}), .SDcols = "calendar_year"]

product_names <- c("EEX DEB CAL", "EEX ATB CAL", "PEGAS TTF CAL", "PEGAS NCG CAL", "PEGAS AUTVTP CAL", "ICE ATW CAL", "ICE BRN CAL", "EEX FEUA MDEC1")
colors <- setNames(c("#007D3C", "#81C07A", "#F07D00", "#FF9966", "#F7BE7F", "#828282", 
                     "993333", "#3399FF"), product_names)

# Valid linetypes include: 'solid', 'dot', 'dash', 'longdash', 'dashdot', 'longdashdot'
calendar_years <- unique(DT$calendar_year)
linetypes <- setNames(c('solid', 'dot', 'dash', 'longdash', 'dashdot', 'longdashdot'), calendar_years)

p <- plot_ly(DT, x = ~ date, y = ~ value, color = ~ product_name, name = ~ variable, colors = colors, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', linetype = ~ calendar_year, linetypes = linetypes,
             connectgaps = TRUE,
             hovertemplate = paste("%{xaxis.title.text}:  %{x}<br>",
                                   "%{yaxis.title.text}:  %{y}<br>")) %>%
  layout(title = "Info",
         xaxis = list(title = "Date"),
         yaxis = list (title = "\u20ac/MWh")) 

p
```

[image: result]

As an alternative approach you could drop the named `linetypes` vector (argument `linetypes = linetypes`) and let plotly choose the linetypes automatically

Comment: In your version, the other lines (products) are not plotted. Do I need the for loop from my code above for this?  In addition,```"EEX DEB CAL-2021"``` and ```"EEX DEB CAL-2023"``` should be the same color.

Comment: They are plotted, I just deselected them to avoid confusion. I'll update regarding the color.

Comment: No this doesn't work, because it only plots ```EEX FEUA MDEC1```.

Comment: The traces should be named with ```....CAL-2021``` and not without the hypchen ```-```. How can I do this?

Comment: This is done via the `name` argument - just updated once again.

Comment: I don't really see the change here for the hypchen ```-```??

Comment: I also updated the image of the plot. You can see the trace names in the legend.